# search methods faster

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I am trying to search 33 .dll to find references for a method, It takes more than 10 minutes to through all the dlls and find references.
Is there a way to speed up things.

each of these dll's approximately has 450 classes and each of this class has approximately 200 methods each

Step that I follow:

```
assemblyName = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(file)
assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyName)

Dim types = assembly.GetTypes()
For Each Type In types
  methods = Type.GetMethods()
  For Each method In methods
    'save method info, class type
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Reflection is notoriously slow. You may need to redesign your solution so it does not need to use reflection. What is your high level requirement? There is probably a better way to achieve it.

Comment: Yes, seriously, what are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your replies... What I am trying to do is like - a recursive find all references of Visual studio. So, its like I start off with finding references to a method and then I find references to all the methods that call this method and so on until I reach a point where I don't have any more method calling these methods(That is, I reach the UI layer, aspx.vb) Any suggestions on what other approaches might let me achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps Mono.Cecil is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You could go through your 33 libraries and store the result of what you're looking for in a database. And then instead of asking your libraries, ask your database, it will be faster and give you directly the right door to knock on...( I mean you can then point directly to the good library and the good class to get more information or instanciate some object,...)

My comment is not that clear so I update my answer.

Before launching a new version , you fill out the database with the new values of your project with a key refering to your version of course. Doing so, when launching the new application, you will not have to wait 10 minutes to get your stuff, because  you will have already used 10 minutes before , hidden, to fill the database. If your application restarts but with no changes in your libraries, the information will still be here too, because the version will be the same.

I wish you good luck anyway for your project...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, These libraries keep changing and getting updated from time to time so storing the data once retrieved in the DB is a little not feasible. I do store it in an array of type struct for the time the application is running but if the application is restarted then we'll need to search the libraries again. Browsing through all the methods is necessary.

Comment: Trying to get some persistence over rebuilding of the application might be indeed a bit tricky.See my answer updated..

Answer (score 1):

I know a lot of fancy tools, including [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) (which is a great tool) use [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil). It's supposed to be better than .NET reflection for some stuff.

Try it out...